# mongo aggregate - expand array of ids in field value into their full objects by querying each

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Within an aggregate, patients have group ids (array of strings).  I've filtered out the ones we need to keep.

My next step is to expand each one, into its full corresponding object that sits in the groups collection.  How can I query each by id and replace each id with its object, within this aggregation?

```
....
$project: {
  patients: {
    patient_id: 1,
    group_ids: {
      how can I query the array of ids that I have as input, to become arrays of their corresponding objects?
    },
  },
},
...
```

[UPDATE]
Of course input and output documents expectation would be helpful:

Input:

```
{
  patient_id: "johndoe",
  group_ids: ['a', 'b']
}
```

groups table:

```
{
  group_id: 'a',
  description: 'groupA desc'
},
{
  group_id: 'b',
  description: 'groupB desc'
}
```

DESIRED RESULT:

```
{
  patient_id: 'johndoe',
  groups: [
    {
      group_id: 'a',
      description: 'groupA desc'
    },
    {
      group_id: 'b',
      description: 'groupB desc'
    }
  ]  
}
```

Comment: Plz post some data with expected output for complete and precise answer.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE**:

**SOLUTION 1**: Using simple [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#equality-match) b/w `patients` and `groups` collections.

```js
db.patients.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "groups",
            localField: "group_ids",
            foreignField: "group_id",
            as: "groups"
        }
    },
    {
        $project: { group_ids: 0 }
    }
]);
```

**SOLUTION 2**: Using [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#join-conditions-and-uncorrelated-sub-queries) with `pipeline` b/w `patients` and `groups` collections.

```js
db.patients.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "groups",
            let: { group_ids: "$group_ids" },
            pipeline: [
                {
                    $match: {
                        $expr: {
                            $in: ["$group_id", "$$group_ids"]
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            as: "groups"
        }
    },
    {
        $project: { group_ids: 0 }
    }
]);
```

Output:

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("605dc2c29b7d5343d009539f"),
    "patient_id" : "johndoe",
    "groups" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("605dc2c29b7d5343d00953a0"),
            "group_id" : "a",
            "description" : "groupA desc"
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("605dc2c29b7d5343d00953a1"),
            "group_id" : "b",
            "description" : "groupB desc"
        }
    ]
}
```

**OLD Answer**

Use [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) operator and loop through the `group_ids` array to build the object when the [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) passes. This is what you need:

```js
$project: {
  patients: {
    patient_id: 1,
    group_ids: {
      $map: {
        input: '$group_ids',
        as: 'group',
        in: { 
          $cond: {
            if: { $in: ['$$group', '$group_ids_to_include'] },
            then: {
              group: "$$group"    // Generate object however you want.
            },
            else: // Do whatever you want.
          }
        },
      },
    },
  },
},
```

Comment: Perhaps I should not have included the filtering part in my question.  What I have above already works to filter the group in groups. I only want to expand what's left.  I included new info in the question to make this more clear.  Thank you

Comment: Thank you again!  I have already done a lookup from a separate collection (other than patients and groups) in order to have what is present in the pipeline.  I need the input to this step to be the one from the previous step.  I was trying every which way to get a lookup working within the group_ids field itself - is that possible?

Comment: Post your query (if the problem still exists) its not clear what you mean. Have you solved it already?

Comment: I ended up writing a separate query and injecting the objects through code.  Thanks